# Angular Expression not updating in view

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working on color picker where i need to select 10 colors , I need to display the value as soon as the color picker select. It is updating the value when we are selecting with for loop but it is not updating the value when we directly print value.
Please check below link - 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-puzsp8-kxtfe1?file=src/app/app.component.html

I might have missed something. But not able to get. 
Lets assume colors is Array object 
and **`<span>{{colors}}</span>`** this will not change value 
**`<span *ngFor="let c of colors">{{c}}</span>`** this one is updating correctly .

Why it is not updating if I print only *colors* . 
Thanks

Comment: Could you please describe a little bit more what you need exactly ?

Comment: `<span>{{colors | json}}</span>` seems to be working. Looks like angular issue> Actually in earlier version if you binded an object, it would simply showup as [object Object]. recently they had added this feature where they pretty print the object. You should never need to bind an object like how you are doing

Comment: @GauravMukherjee , Thanks a lot . It is working with <span>{{colors |  json}}</span> .. I got confused because it was showing string but not updating. Thanks Again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `json` pipe for this.

```
<span>{{colors | json}}</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

i get the same as

`<span *ngFor="let c of colors">{{c}}</span>`

using

`<span>{{colors.toString()}}</span>`

Comment: Thanks . I checked , it was working with colors.toString() .

Answer (score 1):

In earlier version of angular if you binded an object, it would simply show up as `[object Object]`. Recently they had added this feature where they pretty print the object. You should never need to bind an object like how you are doing anyways. Or if you need to, you should convert it to string first

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Yes Earlier I have seen it will display - [object Object]. As per suggestion need to use either pipe or toString() . Thanks